# Strange output in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm encountering a very strange thing while writing a shell script.

Initially I have the following script.

```
OUTPUT_FOLDER=/home/user/output
HOST_FILE=/home/user/host.txt
LOG_DIR=/home/user/log
SLEEPTIME=60

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_FOLDER

while true
do
    rm -f $OUTPUT_FOLDER/*
    DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
    DATETIME=`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
    pssh -h $HOST_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FOLDER
    while read host
    do
        numline=0
        while read line
        do
            if [[ $numline == 0 ]]
            then
                FIELD1=`echo $line | cut -d':' -f2 | cut =d' ' -f2`
            fi
            ((numline+=1))
        done < ${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${host}
        echo "$DATETIME,$FIELD1" >> ${LOG_DIR}/${DATE}.log
    done < $HOST_FILE
    sleep $SLEEPTIME
done
```

When I ran this script, every 60 seconds, I'll see the `$DATETIME,$FIELD1` values in my log file.

What is very strange, is that every 30 seconds or so, after the first minute has passed, I'll see `20160920_120232,`, meaning there was output where there shouldn't be, and I guess because I deleted the contents of my output folder, `FIELD1` is empty.

What is even more strange, is while trying to debug this, I added a few more `echo` statements to print to my log file, and then I deleted those lines. However, they continued to be printed every 30 seconds or so, after the first minute has passed.

What is stranger still is that I then commented out everything inside the `while true` block, that is,

```
OUTPUT_FOLDER=/home/user/output
HOST_FILE=/home/user/host.txt
LOG_DIR=/home/user/log
SLEEPTIME=60

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_FOLDER

while true
do
: << 'END'
    rm -f $OUTPUT_FOLDER/*
    DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
    DATETIME=`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
    pssh -h $HOST_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FOLDER
    while read host
    do
        numline=0
        while read line
        do
            if [[ $numline == 0 ]]
            then
                FIELD1=`echo $line | cut -d':' -f2 | cut =d' ' -f2`
            fi
            ((numline+=1))
        done < ${OUTPUT_FOLDER}/${host}
        echo "$DATETIME,$FIELD1" >> ${LOG_DIR}/${DATE}.log
    done < $HOST_FILE
    sleep $SLEEPTIME
END
done
```

Even with this script, where I'm expecting nothing to be printed to my log file, I see my previous `echo` statements that I have deleted, and the lines with the empty `FIELD1`. I have checked that I'm running the correct version of the script each time.

What is going on?

Comment: Can there be any background process you are not aware of?

Comment: Did you restarted the process after you made changes? And made sure the old process is really not running?

Comment: `fuser -k /path/to/file`, to ensure that everything writing to that file is dead, is your friend. Or just `fuser /path/to/file`, and making sure the list of processes with handles on it is what you expect.

Comment: Beyond that, right now this question is very much suffering from the lack of a reproducer -- if nobody else can actually see the problem, nobody can tell if their guesses are correct or if their proposed fix actually works. If still in a place of trying to pin down what's going on even after using `fuser`, I might pull out [sysdig](http://sysdig.org/) with a query to process all writes to the relevant file across the operating system (vs `strace` tracking only one process with very high performance overhead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it and couldn't. Thre is no reason for this script (when commented as you have) to produce any output.

There are couple of cases:

1. As others pointed out, there may be some other script writing to your log file
2. You may have left few instances of this script running on other terminals
3. You may be running this script from crontab once every 5 mins

In order to rule out possibilities, do a "ps -aef" and check out all the processes that could resemble the name of your script. To catch things from crontab, you may have to watch the output of "ps -aef" a big longer (or just check in the crontab entries).

Comment: Thanks! Turns out, I did have a few instances of this script running in the background. Once I killed them, the output is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure, it could be a the actual reason for the screw-up. You have an incorrect usage of `cut` in line number `22` which could have mangled the `FIELD1` inadvertently.

```
FIELD1=`echo $line | cut -d':' -f2 | cut =d' ' -f2`
#                                        ^ incorrect usage of the delimiter '-d' flag
```

which should have been used as

```
FIELD1=`echo $line | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2`
#                                        ^ Proper usage of the '-d' flag with space delimiter
```

I tried to capture the piped command output to see if the last command could have succeeded and below was my observation.

```
echo $line | cut -d':' -f2 | cut =d' ' -f2;echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
cut: =d : No such file or directory     # --> Error from the failed 'cut' command
0 0 1                                   # --> Return codes of each of the command being piped
```

Also, if you have been a `bash` purist, you have avoided the legacy ``` `` ```  style command expansion and used a `$(cmd)` syntax like,

```
FIELD1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2)
```

Another simpler way would have been to avoid use of `cut` & `echo` and do pure bash string-manipulation.

Assuming your `$line` contains `:` and  de-limited string e.g.`"What Hell:Hello World"` and you are trying to extract the `World` part as I could see, just do

```
FIELD1="${line##* }"   # Strips-off characters until last occurrence of whitespace
```